# Jquery Modal Dialog disables dialog in Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility Mode

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I didn't see any answered questions about this. Currently I use Jquery UI Dialog boxes with modal set true.

```
            $("#popup").dialog
        ({
            height: 550,
            width: 750,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            position: 'top',
            title: "Popup",
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            closeText: "",
            open: function(type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo('form:first');
            }
        });
    }
```

The popup works and correctly fires but while in IE 8 comparability mode it grays out everything including the popup box. It appears the overlay covers everything and makes it impossible to click anything. I hope someone else has hit this and has an idea.

UPDATE

Looks like after making a really dumbed down test page it was a problem with the css coming from a masterpage that I am required to use. The css forces position:relative which seems to be the problem. Since I can't edit the css for the masterpage, I instead put in this code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

which forces the browser to not use compatibility mode for my page, and it seems to be working.

Thanks for the comments and time!

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue; is there anything in your CSS for the #popup element that could be preventing the proper style from jquery-ui (or anything that's overriding the 'ui-widget-overlay' class)? Other things that could be helpful to know include whether or not you're seeing IE8 throw an error to the javascript developer tools, and what version of jquery-ui you're running.

Comment: Jquery-ui version is 1.8.7, The only places I see ui-widget-overlay are in the jquery ui css, .ui-widget-overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; } and .ui-widget-overlay { background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); }. The IE8 developer tools are not throwing any errors that I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) and tried your code in FF4.01, Chrome 11, IE8, and IE8 Compatibility mode (IE7) and they all seem to work.

Check out the ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/y7VGy/)***:

```
$("#popup").dialog(
{
    height: 550,
    width: 750,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    position: 'top',
    title: "Popup",
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    closeText: "",
    open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo('form:first'); }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that is set true when I have the problem. I have been having to set it to false to make the site work.

Comment: Do you see the issue in that jsFiddle?  I couldn't reproduce your error.

Comment: I'm not having the same problem there. So perhaps my page has something else going on with it. I'll try to make a really dumbed down version to test.

Comment: Now ... the only difference is my test uses 1.8.13.  Maybe try upgrading to that?

Comment: @Scott your jsfiddle link not even opening in IE8

Comment: @user2826111 IE8 not working is more likely a jsFiddle issue. That said, I did get IE8 to work when you use quirks mode.  Here's a jsFiddle that uses jQuery UI 1.9.1 http://jsfiddle.net/y7VGy/136/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and, unfortunately, I also needed the compatibility mode in every page.
Finally, I found out this workaround:

```
open: function(type, data) { 
    $(this).parent().appendTo('form:first'); 
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').appendTo('form:first');
}
```